# Skyscanner response contains so many OutboundLegId and InboundLegId?

Tags: php, api, curl, skyscanner

I am using **Skyscanner** travel api and getting response successfully.

There are so many OutboundLegId and InboundLegId in the response.

I just want to show flights for the selected destination. please see attachment.

For this, Should I extract all the **OutboundLegId and InboundLegId** for required data or just first array record?

http://business.skyscanner.net/portal/en-GB/Documentation/FlightsLivePricingQuickStart

and I used below code:-

[Skyscanner API for all airport locations and Travel API using CURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38867583/skyscanner-api-for-all-airport-locations-and-travel-api-using-curl/39328771#39328771)

Because each contains agents and other data.

Should I show all data on my site or need to use first 5-10 records only?

Please advice me on this.

[image]

Comment: Hi have you been able to fetch the results from the API according the screenshot attached? I’m also trying to implement similar for a mobile app but the APIs doesn’t seem to support the above. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in the query string with session key **&pageindex=1&pagesize=10**

Comment: There are many deep link urls. During checking test harness, after getting data they again click on fetch button. This loads data as above. Here by I am confused how to load this data in one.