# Skyscanner API for all hotel locations using CURL

Tags: php, api, curl, skyscanner

I am trying to fetch geo catalogue data from skyscanner api. I have read documentation 
http://business.skyscanner.net/portal/en-GB/Documentation/ApiOverview

I have created api key. I am hitting api successfully and getting result same as on the 
http://business.skyscanner.net/portal/en-GB/Documentation/HotelsLivePricingQuickStart

I am hitting:-

http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/hotels/autosuggest/v2/UK/GBP/en-GB/.$cityname.?apikey=prtl6749387986743898559646983194"

I want to get responce in JSON. Is it possible??

I have successfully get flight live prices here is link [[Get error in using skyscanner Api of flight pricing in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42106997/get-error-in-using-skyscanner-api-of-flight-pricing-in-php]) using POST method.

Comment: did you write code and having issue or you are expecting some one to write code for you ?? If you choose second contact some people pay them they will do it. If first where is your code what is the issue ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$checkin_date = "2017-05-05";
$checkout_date = "2017-05-08";
$guests = 10;
$rooms=  4;
$country_iso_code = "UK";
$country_currency = "EUR";
$locale_lang = "en-GB";
$url = "http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/hotels/liveprices/v2/$country_iso_code/$country_currency/$locale_lang/27539733/$checkin_date/$checkout_date/$guests/$rooms?apiKey=prtl6749387986743898559646983194";

$ch = curl_init();
$http_header = ["Content_type : application/json"];
$options = [
CURLOPT_URL => $url,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $http_header
];
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($response);
```

//Response in Json

This is just basic code how you hit the api of skyscanner to get the data in json format using curl